# Кэширование большого количества больших файлов в бразуере

Tags: html5, google-chrome, кэширование, localstorage, хранилище

Планируется разработка проекта, который позволит в трехмерном пространстве просматривать и расставлять объекты (например, простая плоскость, на которой размещены объекты дома и дерева). Проект для браузера, использует библиотеку three.js (который в свою очередь использует canvas), но суть не в этом.

Предполагается, что в проекте будут использованы тысячи разных моделей объектов (в формате .obj) и текстур (предположительно, .jpg), подгружаемых по необходимости. Все это добро, если его вместе скачать, будет занимать больше половины гигабайта.

Вопрос: если не обращать внимания на это и просто указывать ссылку на файл, как будет происходить кэширование? Есть ли какое-то ограничение на количество, объем, формат или время хранения файлов, скачанных с сайта?

Искал способ хранить скачанный файл на стороне браузера (Chrome), много раз наступал на chrome.fileSystem, который, если не ошибаюсь, доступен только для приложений Chrome, а не для сайтов. Поэтому второй вопрос по той же теме - есть ли какое-то хранилище в браузере для хранения такого объема данных?

Спасибо за советы

UPD: Нашел информацию о HTML5 Application Cache, где указано, что во многих браузерах, включая Chrome, ограничения на размер хранимых данных нет. Пока что не имею возможности испытать, но интересно послушать мнение тех, кто уже использовал его